# Auto_Increment not working on insert query

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, primary-key, auto-increment

Need help how to solve this problem...
I have created a users table which has following columns

```
Create table users
(
  uid int(10) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  uname varchar(50),
  password varchar(50),
  email varchar(50)
);
```

when i insert values with `uid` it executes successfully :

```
Insert into users values(1,'ABC','Helloworld','ABC@gmail.com');
```

but when i try without `uid`

```
Insert into users values('SDC','Helloworld','SDC@gmail.com');
```

it does not execute successfully and gives an error

```
ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

my `uid` has `AUTO_INCREMENT` so it should automatically increase..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course `auto_increment` is working correctly.  You just need to learn best practices about using `insert`.  *Always* list all the columns (unless you really, really know what you are doing):

```
Insert into users (uname, password, email)
    values('SDC', 'Helloworld', 'SDC@gmail.com');
```

The id column will be auto-incremented.  If you don't list the columns, then MySQL expects values for all columns, including the auto-incremented one.